# accessing google analytics data through an api

Tags: api, google-analytics, statistics

Does anyone know if it is possible to access any of google analytics data from the API?

I am using eCommerce and wanted to be able to pull out the best selling products into a most wanted list.

Does anyone know if this is possible and how it would be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the API is documented here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/

HelloWorld example here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api